# Can't Install Ubuntu on my NVME But It runs from the Bootable USB device

Tags: 22.04, ssd, usb-installation, nvme

I downloaded the iso for Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu website and Burned it to my Sandisk 32 gb pendrive using Balenaetcher because I saw in in the tutorials. Ubuntu is running from the bootable pendrive but when I tried to install it by erasing my previous windows it erased everything on my ssd and gave me an error message that it could not be installed. My PC is new I recently bought it. It has a HP EX900 500GB NVME SSD. Now I have no Windows on my ssd and it is not showing up in BIOS. I can use ubuntu from Bootable drive but It is not being installed.Please!I need help.

Comment: Did you follow the official tutorial for the install?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Yes. I was able to finally install Ubuntu on my desktop. And I've been using it for 2 days. Seems like there were one or more corrupted files in the iso in my bootable media. I downloaded a fresh copy of the iso and It installed without any problem.